# jQuery change value of elements after drag and drop with html5

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have a page with two elements, both contains several fields. One of those fields have the id `SortingOrderHidden`. If i change the order of the elements with jquery and html5 i also want to change the value of this field.
I try it this way:

```
 var dropedElementSortingOrder = 0;
    var draggedElementSortingOrder = 0;
     $(function () {
            function handleDragStart(e) {
                this.style.opacity = '0.5';
                dragSrcEl = this;
                e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
                dropedElementSortingOrder = $(this).find(".SortingOrderHidden");
                e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
            }

            var cols = document.querySelectorAll('.ProcedureDrag');
            [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
                col.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
                col.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
                col.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
                col.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
                col.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
                col.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
            });
            function handleDragOver(e) {
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } return false;
            }
            function handleDragEnter(e) {
                this.classList.add('over');
            }
            function handleDragLeave(e) {
                this.classList.remove('over');
            }
            function handleDrop(e) {
                if (e.stopPropagation) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
                if (dragSrcEl != this) {
                    draggedElementSortingOrder = $(this).find(".SortingOrderHidden");
                    var a = dropedElementSortingOrder.val();
                    var b = draggedElementSortingOrder.val();
                    dropedElementSortingOrder.val(b);
                    draggedElementSortingOrder.val(a);
                    var c = dropedElementSortingOrder.val();
                    var d = draggedElementSortingOrder.val();
                    $('#SortingOrderChanged').val(true);
                    dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                    this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
                }
                return false;
            }

            function handleDragEnd(e) {
                [].forEach.call(cols, function (col) {
                    col.classList.remove('over');
                }); this.style.opacity = '1.0';
            }
    });
```

but it never changed the value of the element i take to move. The other one who is switching the position is work fine. Also in the debugger (Google Chrome) everything seem fine. The values (with the letters a,b,c,d) are as expected.

Here the example in JSFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/gvKCL/2/
Edit: I just regongnized that if the inputs are type="text" they don´t even get any change in value. So here is the version with hidden, which is works exactly as my program: http://jsfiddle.net/gvKCL/10/

**Edit: Solution:**
Here you will find the running example: http://jsfiddle.net/gvKCL/14/

I had to change the handleDrop like:

```
 function handleDrop(e) {
     if (e.stopPropagation) {
         e.stopPropagation();
     }
     if (dragSrcEl != this) {
         dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
         this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
         var draggedElementSortingOrder = $(this).find(".SortingOrderHidden");
         var dropedElementSortingOrder = $(dragSrcEl).find(".SortingOrderHidden");
         var a = dropedElementSortingOrder.val();
         var b = draggedElementSortingOrder.val();
         dropedElementSortingOrder.val(b);
         draggedElementSortingOrder.val(a);
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

```
this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
```

When you update the `.val()` of your fields, the content of `e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');` isn't updated. At the end of the function, when you set `this.innerHTML`, you are actually overwriting your updates and the field is reverted to it's original state.

Comment: Thank you very much. It drive me crazy and then it is so easy ^^. I edited the question with the corrected code :)